# Find user's active time in a redirected app

Tags: web-development-server, user-activity

I have a scenario in which I am redirecting the user to another app from my app on a button click. I wanted to know if it is possible in any way to determine how much time the user spent on the other app? (Note that it is possible the user directly goes to the phone's home screen from the redirected app)

Also, is the same thing possible in case of redirecting to another website from my website?

Comment: Not unless you integrate with the other app / website, the other app / website tracks the progress, stores it on their server and lets you access that data remotely.

Comment: As you can see, I am fairly new to this platform so feel free to edit the tags and add more relevant tags so that the question may reach the appropriate audience.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. That's what I was expecting. Just wanted to confirm it with the expert community here. Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: I have removed the Android and IOS related tags because this seems to be a generic question ... not related specifically to either Android or IOS ... or any other app platform.

Comment: And you seem to have asked two unrelated questions.  About app redirection and website redirection.